# Zoom in and zoom out option not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

The zoom in and zoom out option is working on the map, but its invisible, it's not appearing. Any help please?

Here is the coding: (Ignore the JEVLOCATION_LAT/LON)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map-canvas {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px
       }
     </style>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
     <script> function initialize() {   var city = new google.maps.LatLng({{Latitude:JEVLOCATION_LAT}},
 {{Latitude:JEVLOCATION_LON}});   var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 14,
     center: city,
     mapTypeControl: true,
     mapTypeControlOptions: {
       style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
     },
     zoomControl: true,
     zoomControlOptions: {
       style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
     }   };   var map = new google.maps.Map(
       document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{Latitude:JEVLOCATION_LAT}},{{Latitude:JEVLOCATION_LON}});
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   position: myLatlng,   map:
 map,   title:"" });   var panoramaOptions = {
     position: city,
     pov: {
       heading: 34,
       pitch: 10
     }   };   var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),
 panoramaOptions);   map.setStreetView(panorama); }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     </script>   </head>   <body>
     <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
     <div id="pano" style="left:0px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Here is a picture of the map:

http://i1382.photobucket.com/albums/ah268/Lucas_Maddox/mapzoomwontshow_zpscd0118c9.png

Thank you!

Comment: Your exact code (with a different LatLng object) seems to be working and displays the zoom buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/m2p2e4dd/1/ Can you share a link of your site live? It's tough because I don't know if my English version of maps is different or not than yours. A live link would really help.

Comment: Are you familiar with a DOM inspector, like Firefox Inspector, Firefox Firebug, Chrome DevTools, or IE Developer Tools? I'd like you to inspect the HTML for the "Terminos de uso" in the corner using an inspector. Once you see its HTML in the DOM, look up a couple lines for its grandparent element with the class "gm-style-cc", and click on that guy's sibling element right after it with the classes "gmnoprint gm-style-mtc". In my copy of maps, this div has the zoom and street-view controls. Look at its CSS, and at its children with their CSS, see if there's anything making it invisible.

Comment: http://juninarg.com/index.php/component/jevlocations/detail/3/1/biblioteca-publica-municipal-bernardino-rivadavia Sorry that its in spanish, but I will try that DOM inspector you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your maps are not functioning correctly because too much code has been duplicated.

You have multiple `<DOCTYPE>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<div id="map-canvas">` html. All your JS functions are duplicated too, and then they're called multiple times. This means everything gets a bit confused and in your case, it just can't figure out where to place the Zoom Options.

You need to refactor/clean up your code. Then the map options will start working.

Here's how...

...fair warning, WALL OF TEXT INCOMING! I apologize for the length of this post, but I want you to know the changes I made and why. It's intent is not to belittle, just to get your site working as fast as possible and help you avoid any issues in the future. :)

I have also made some 'best practice' coding suggestions that you are free to ignore. However, these are industry-standard practices only meant to make your coding life easier in the future.

#### 1. Put these lines in your first `<head>` element, which is at the top of your page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://juninarg.com/images/jevents/jevlocations/53f2b4d97d8b50.48312034.jpeg" />
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* below is recently added 'best practices' styling */
.content-inner {
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
}
.image-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
#intro-img {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#static-map {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.title {
  font-size: 18pt;
}
#content p {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
#map-canvas {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#pano {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.mod_events_latest_table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
</style>
```

The first part is from your own `<style>`+`<meta>` tags in the middle of the page, the remainder is additions by me for the HTML coming up.

Note that you're not technically allowed to put `<style>` or `<meta>` tags in the middle of a page, like you have, they're only allowed inside the `<head>` according to HTML specifications.

Further, the meta tag had a broken link, now fixed in the above code (the text was repeating the .com part).

I also removed the `height: 100%` from your `html, body, #map-canvas` line as it seemed to serve no purpose, and it can be incompatible with certain combinations of HTML unless you're careful.

#### 2: Replace everything from `<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->` to `<!-- // MAIN CONTENT -->` with this HTML:

***Be sure to back everything up first!***

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div id="content">  
  <div class="inner content-inner clearfix">
    <div id="intro-img" class="image-wrapper">
      <img class="lazyload" src="http://juninarg.com/cache/jalazyload/300x225.png" longdesc="http://juninarg.com/images/jevents/jevlocations/53f2b4d97d8b50.48312034.jpeg" itemprop="image" />
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">Biblioteca Pública Municipal Bernardino Rivadavia</h1>
    <p>Rivadavia 28<br />Ciudad de Junín<br />6000, Partido de Junín, Provincia de Buenos Aires, Argentina<br /><br /><strong>Tel: (236) 463-1600 Int. 229</strong></p>
    <div id="static-map" class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Argentina&zoom=13&size=520x250&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.-34.59288025,-60.94636154" alt="Static Map" width="520" height="250">
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {  
          var city = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.59288025,-60.94636154);  
          var mapOptions = {    
            zoom: 14,    
            center: city,    
            mapTypeControl: true,    
            mapTypeControlOptions: {      
              style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU    
            }, 
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {    
              style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
            }
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(      
            document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
            mapOptions
          );
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.59288025,-60.94636154);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position: myLatlng,  
            map: map,  
            title:""
          });  
          var panoramaOptions = {    
            position: city,    
            pov: {      
              heading: 34,      
              pitch: 10    
            }  
          };  
          var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('pano'), 
            panoramaOptions
          );
          map.setStreetView(panorama);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/system/jalazyload/assets/lazyload/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function lazyloadinit() {
        jQuery("img.lazyload").lazyload({
          failure_limit: 10,
          threshold: 0,
          effect: "show",
          skip_invisible: false,
          load: function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("lazyload");

          },
          appear: function() {
            jQuery(this).attr("data-original", jQuery(this).attr("longdesc") || "").removeAttr("longdesc");
          }
        });
      };
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        lazyloadinit();
      });
    </script>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
    </div>  
    <div id="pano" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
    </div>
    <p>Por una Ordenanza del día 7 de agosto de 1926, se dispuso la creación de una BIBLIOTECA PUBLICA MUNICIPAL, que debería denominarse "Bernardino Rivadavia", en honor al prócer. Fue inaugurada oficialmente el 15 de noviembre de 1936.</p>
    <p>La Biblioteca cuenta con aproximadamente 16.000 volúmenes, donde se pueden encontrar libros de textos, novelas, cuentos, literatura infantil, diccionarios, libros de lenguas, etc. Además de folletos, revistas y diarios.<br />Posee una Sala de Lectura y otra destinada a Estudio e Investigación.</p>
    <p>Ver más: <a href="http://www.junin.gov.ar/index.php?sector=3&amp;div=10003&amp;divLnk=13&amp;sdiv=1006&amp;lT=0">http://www.junin.gov.ar/index.php?sector=3&amp;div=10003&amp;divLnk=13&amp;sdiv=1006&amp;lT=0</a></p>
    <fieldset class="adminform">
      <legend>Upcoming Events</legend>
      <table class="mod_events_latest_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="mod_events_latest_first">
            <span class="mod_events_latest_date">Thu Oct 23 @ 3:00PM</span> - <span class="mod_events_latest_date">05:00PM</span><br /><span class="mod_events_latest_content"><a href="/index.php/eventdetail/21/-/talleres-culturales-photoshop-1-x-prof-marcelo-mels-biblioteca-publica-municipal-bernardino-rivadavia-junin-buenos-aires"  target="_top" >Talleres Culturales - Photoshop 1 x Prof. Marcelo Mels, Biblioteca Pública Municipal Bernardino Rivadavia, Junín, Buenos Aires</a></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mod_events_latest">
            <span class="mod_events_latest_date">Thu Oct 30 @ 3:00PM</span> - <span class="mod_events_latest_date">05:00PM</span><br /><span class="mod_events_latest_content"><a href="/index.php/eventdetail/22/-/talleres-culturales-photoshop-1-x-prof-marcelo-mels-biblioteca-publica-municipal-bernardino-rivadavia-junin-buenos-aires"  target="_top" >Talleres Culturales - Photoshop 1 x Prof. Marcelo Mels, Biblioteca Pública Municipal Bernardino Rivadavia, Junín, Buenos Aires</a></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <strong>View all events <a href='/index.php/component/jevents/monthcalendar/2014/10/-?loclkup_fv=3&amp;Itemid=0' target='_top'>here</a></strong>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- // MAIN CONTENT -->
```

Demo example (supports map, I didn't add LazyLoad yet): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dlonj

#### Suggested Changes implemented above

1. Remove all inline CSS. This sort of boils down to personal choice, but I never recommend using inline CSS unless you have to. All the CSS in the html can be moved to a `<style>` tag (or better yet, a .css file) to make the code much easier to read.
2. You can combine several elements together. No need to have 4 elements do the work of 1. It just makes the code harder to manage and bugfix.

For example:

```
<h3><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva;"><span style="color: #000000;">
```

...can be rewritten as...

```
<h3 class="title">
```

...and then we could put this in your CSS, in that first `head`:

```
.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: verdana, geneva;
  color: #000000;
}
```

3. Search engines rely on `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc, tags to get a sense of document organization. For the best search engine optimization, it is not recommended to use h3 to wrap multiple paragraphs of text, or to wrap a single image. This will only confuse search engines. Instead, take your main title text (Biblioteca Pública Municipal Bernardino Rivadavia) and wrap that in an `<h1>` tag. Put the other paragraphs/images in `<p>` or `<div>` tags as appropriate.
4. When picking a font-family, always include a `serif` or `sans-serif` at the end of your family list. You specify `font-family: verdana, geneva;`. If a computer does not have either font installed (Linux computers come to mind), the browser will have to do a best guess and may pick something completely wrong looking, like a Times New Roman font. Writing `serif` (means fonts with little flags on the tips, like Times New Roman) or `sans-serif` (no flags, like Verdana) helps solve that a bit. So use `font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;`.
5. Keep your Javascript organized looking or it'll be very hard to debug issues.

Don't write this...

```
function initialize() {  var city = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.59288025,-60.94636154);  var mapOptions = {    zoom: 14,
```

...when you could hit Enter a few times and get this...

```
function initialize() {
   var city = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.59288025,-60.94636154);
   var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
```

More important than saving a few bytes in download time is keeping your code easy-to-read.

6. Never have more than one `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`. It's an easy to mistake to make, especially if you're copying-and-pasting code from another page, but these 4 tags are extremely important and duplicating them will produce unpredictable results. It forces browsers to do a "best guess" and try to combine the tags cleverly, which is to say, unpredictably. Your page may look great on one browser, and look terrible on another that wasn't clever enough to combine right.
7. Double-check your duplicate JS content. Do you need the duplicates, or was it an accident you can remove? You have two `initialize()`, two `google.maps.event.addDomListener`, and three `lazyloadinit()`. I suspect you only need one of each of those. Any more will just confuse the browser and raise Javascript errors.
8. Remove duplicate HTML elements with the same ID, or rename the duplicates to something else. You have two `#map-canvas`. This is definitely against specs... it forces the browser to make a "best guess" when called in Javascript. When you ask it to drop a map on `#map-canvas`, it has to decide... "should I use the first one, the second one, maybe both?" Again, I suspect something was just copied-pasted accidentally. But watch for these things or weird results may come out (such as Zoom Options just randomly disappearing).
9. Avoid using `<br />` to separate block-level elements (like `<p>`, `<div>`) when `margin` CSS would do better. You *can* use it and it will render as expected. However, the `<br>` tag is about content... it means "break this line of text by inserting a new line"... but you're not using it that way. You're using it as "I want to add spacing after this map". That's not content, that's formatting, which is recommended to be placed in CSS. And practically, it means less tags to deal with and more control (you can set margin to 1.5 lines if you want, not possible with just `<br>` tags).
10. Avoid using `<center>` tags. It's not supported in HTML5 and is generally being 'phased out'. Practically, there's no harm in using it at the moment. But the industry is moving away from "formatting in the html" to "formatting in the css", to keep everything organized and easy to get around. So for better organization, I suggest getting rid of `<center>` and using CSS like `text-align: center` (for wrappers of inline elements) or `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` (for block elements).
11. There's a stray `</form>` closing tag, remove it.

#### 3. Pick a DOCTYPE

Earlier, I mentioned a few duplicate DOCTYPES. You have two different ones in here... XHTML `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` and HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Which one do you want? I would suggest the latter... HTML5 is a lot more flexible/forgiving in its rules, except it doesn't support `<center>` tags, but that's a small tradeoff for the new tags and features you are allowed to use. To use it, copy it out of your duplicate and replace your first line of code (the other doctype) with it.

Answer (score 0):

I made an update on the coding, got it from google, like a copy and paste and edited with the stuff i needed to add. But there aren't any controls or markes on the map, any help? http://juninarg.com/index.php/component/jevlocations/detail/3/1/biblioteca-publica-municipal-bernardino-rivadavia Thanks for your time, I read the whole post you added and it helped me a lot